# Replacing the xml node value fails to update in xml file

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to update node value using following powershell script

```
$XMLContents = [XML] (Get-content "C:\Test.xml")
$XPath="/Parameters/Parameter[ParameterName='pTxtRuntimeUserName']/ParameterValue"
$MachineNameInXML= Select-XML -XML $XMLContents -XPath $Xpath
$Userstring=$($MachineNameInXML.Node.'#text')
$Userstring = $Userstring.Replace("WIN2K8R25\administrator","WIN2K8R25\ABC")
$Userstring
$XMLContents.Save("C:\Test.xml")
```

When i display $Userstring , it displays the replaced value "WIN2K8R25\ABC" correctly but in xml file it was not updated. It is still the old username "WIN2K8R25\administrator".

My XML file is having many parameter node, I have copied some sample node values alone.

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter IsEncrypted="False">
      <ParameterName>pTxtRuntimeUserName</ParameterName> 
      <ParameterValue>WIN2K8R25\administrator</ParameterValue> 
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter IsEncrypted="False">
      <ParameterName>pTxtABC</ParameterName> 
      <ParameterValue>XYCr</ParameterValue> 
    </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

I am unable to find where do i miss. what am i missing in this ?

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
$Userstring = $Userstring.Replace("WIN2K8R25\administrator","WIN2K8R25\ABC")
```

It looks like you're just reassigning the `$Userstring` variable to a new value, but this has no effect on the contents of the DOM.

How about adding a new line after that:

```
$MachineNameInXML.Node.InnerText = $Userstring
```

Or you could skip using the `$Userstring` variable altogether:

```
$XMLContents = [XML] (Get-content "C:\Test.xml")
$XPath="/Parameters/Parameter[ParameterName='pTxtRuntimeUserName']/ParameterValue"
$MachineNameInXML= Select-XML -XML $XMLContents -XPath $Xpath
$MachineNameInXML.Node.InnerText = $MachineNameInXML.Node.InnerText.Replace("WIN2K8R25\administrator","WIN2K8R25\ABC")
$XMLContents.Save("C:\Test.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$path = "C:\Test.xml"
$XMLContents = [XML] (Get-content $path)
$Node = $XMLContents.SelectNodes("/Parameters/Parameter[ParameterName='pTxtRuntimeUserName']/")
$Node[0].ParameterValue = $Node[0].ParameterValue.Replace("WIN2K8R25\administrator","WIN2K8R25\ABC")
$XMLContents.Save($path)
```

Might be a better looking way to do it, but as long as it's only one node with that paramtername it should work.